# IGNORE x LINE into a INFILE command does not work with x >1

Tags: php, mysql, import-from-csv

I use the INFILE function to copy a CSV file into a mysql database table, but I am not able to skip the first 2 lines automatically with IGNORE command. If I remove them in the CSV file it works and works also if I remove only the first line and I change the command as "IGNORE 1 LINES". Why I cannot skip the first two lines?

CSV file (data.csv) is as follow

```
Extraction Date: 2018-08-08
ID;name;surname;address;age
1;Alfred;Kennedy.Carbon Street;29
2;Mollie;Bush;First Avenue;22
3;Carl;Randolph;Second street;23
4;Anthony;Burger;Third Street; 33
```

The PHP code is as follow:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO table table_data
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
  IGNORE 2 LINES
  (ID, name , surname, address, age)
  ";

  mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Try using `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot Nigel !